# Visual Studio 2019 .netCore is not debugging

Tags: asp.net-core, visual-studio-2019

I wasn't working on this project for a month.today I run this project because there were some bugs.

I put some debug points to controllers but they didn't hit. Then I tryed some solutions and it starts hit but not shows values on cursor. There's my settings I can show more if you ask how can I fix it.

[debug image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lnr4L.png)

[build](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PxStM.png)

FINALLY

I change it to debug and it start works again. Thank you all.
[debug](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IAwXx.png)

Comment: Okay I added build image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually when you are debugging hover your cursor over the variable and you don't see anything is that the build config is in Release mode.
In Release mode, the compiler optimizes the code and can remove / move the definition of a variable.
When you debug, the variable does not exist and Visual Studio displays nothing.
Sometime I see `Can't display the value because the code is optimized`.

First check your select debug on Solution Configuration :

[image]

Once I got a project that I couldn't debug. In the solution file, I see this :

```
Microsoft Visual Studio Solution File, Format Version 12.00
# Visual Studio Version 16
VisualStudioVersion = 16.0.31019.35
MinimumVisualStudioVersion = 10.0.40219.1
Project("{9A19103F-16F7-4668-BE54-9A1E7A4F7556}") = "Console1", "Console1.csproj", "{97BEE082-AF7F-4A3C-8B7E-6E743ED9241C}"
EndProject
Global
    GlobalSection(SolutionConfigurationPlatforms) = preSolution
        Debug|Any CPU = Debug|Any CPU
        Release|Any CPU = Release|Any CPU
    EndGlobalSection
    GlobalSection(ProjectConfigurationPlatforms) = postSolution
        {97BEE082-AF7F-4A3C-8B7E-6E743ED9241C}.Debug|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Debug|Any CPU
        {97BEE082-AF7F-4A3C-8B7E-6E743ED9241C}.Debug|Any CPU.Build.0 = Release|Any CPU
        {97BEE082-AF7F-4A3C-8B7E-6E743ED9241C}.Release|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Release|Any CPU
        {97BEE082-AF7F-4A3C-8B7E-6E743ED9241C}.Release|Any CPU.Build.0 = Release|Any CPU
    EndGlobalSection
    GlobalSection(SolutionProperties) = preSolution
        HideSolutionNode = FALSE
    EndGlobalSection
    GlobalSection(ExtensibilityGlobals) = postSolution
        SolutionGuid = {BA661F8F-52EB-4D00-B804-56F1B00021AC}
    EndGlobalSection
EndGlobal
```

See this line :

```
{***}.Debug|Any CPU.Build.0 = Release|Any CPU
```

The Solution Configuration `Debug` reference the build configuration `Release`. When I select `Debug` in Visual Studio, the build do in Release mode. I replaced by `{***}.Debug|Any CPU.Build.0 = Debug|Any CPU` and the debug worked.